# Binding const T (&ref)[N] to object of type T[N]

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c++11, reference

I'm noticing odd semantics wrt binding references to pointers and arrays that differ in the constness of the pointed-to and array elements respectively.  With pointers this fails predictably:

```
int* p{};
const int*& p_ref{p};
```

```
non-const lvalue reference to type 'const int *' cannot bind to a  value of unrelated type 'int *'
```

Makes sense, pointer-to-int and pointer-to-const-int are two different types, adding a `const` before the `&` allows the compiler to produce a temporary, which works, but doesn't change the above.

However, what I thought should be analogous with arrays is not

```
int arr[5]{};
const int (&arr_ref)[5]{arr};
```

clang and gcc both compile the above without complaint, but why? I'm binding a non-const reference to `const int[5]` to an object of type `int[5]`. Why is this allowed?

**Update:** A similar issue is described by Gotcha #32 (page 82) in [*C++ Gotchas*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125185) by Stephen C. Dewhurst

Comment: Also consider `int *const &p_ref{p};`.

Comment: @Hurkyl That's just normal binding a const ref to a non const variable though?

Comment: continental const placement seems relevant here: https://kuhllib.com/2012/01/17/continental-const-placement/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With your first example, if that was allowed, it would be possible to break const correctness.

```
int *p{};
const int*& p_ref{p}; // pretend this is okay
const int x = 10;
p_ref = &x;           // storing the address of a const int in a const int*, okay
*p = 5;               // Should be okay, because p is int*, not const int*,
                      // but oops, just modified a const value
```

A reference to an array does not have this problem, because you cannot point an array somewhere else (since it's not a pointer).

There's a similar problem with pointers to pointers. It is often the case that we store the address of a non-const `T` in a `const T*`. Because this is okay, people tend to think it should be possible to store the address of a `T*` in a `const T**`. But that leads to the same problem as with the reference example above:

```
int* p;
const int** pp = &p;  // forbidden, but pretend it's okay for now
const int x = 10;
*pp = &x;              // storing the address of a const int in a const int*, okay
*p = 5;                // oops, modified a const int
```